# Measuring spatial overlap in 2 different ways - paired t-test?

Tags: t-test, paired-comparisons

I have collected spatial data (GPS points and foraging heights) for a bunch of territorial animals. Until recently, these types of data were only analyzed in two dimensions (2D). However, 3D analysis is now available and I'm working on a paper that compares 2D and 3D estimates of spatial overlap. I define spatial overlap as being simply the area (2D) or volume (3D) of space overlapped divided by the total area or volume of the territory. This produces a proportion which I convert into a percentage.

So basically for every bird I have a 2D percent overlap and a 3D percent overlap. I would like to compare these two different measures to see if one overestimates overlap compared to the other. It seems to make sense to me to use a paired t-test or the non-parametric equivalent (Paired-Sample Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test) as opposed to a normal t-test or Mann-Whitney U. Anybody have thoughts?

Comment: Many people would seek insight by *exploring* these data rather than testing them.  Have you drawn a scatterplot?

Comment: None of the classical tests is correct when the data are likely to show spatial dependence. There is literature on this, but you are likely to get shot down by more statistically-minded ecologists if you don't be up-front about the limitations of what you are doing. For example, you might to simulate to get a handle on P-values. I agree with @whuber and add that using differences between means or pr(X > Y) as descriptive statistics alone may be useful.